# Regex expression to filter src

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried to use a regex to filter a img src, but it does not work:

[jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/b4hEj/3/)

```
var patt= src\s*=\s*"(.+?)";

var result=patt.exec('<a href="http://www.google.de/imgres" ><img id="image" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxQTEhUUEhQUFRQVFRQVFRQVFBQVFxQUFRUXFhQUFBUYHCggGBolHBQUITEhJSkrLi4uFx8zODMsNygtLisBCgoKDg0OFBAQGiwkHyQsLCwsLCwtLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLP" /></a>')

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Define "does not work". What is the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You hadn't the right syntax for regex literals.

It's

```
var patt=/src\s*=\s*"(.+?)"/;
```

See [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

If you just want the `src`, use

```
console.log(result[1]);
```

Comment: I believe `[^"]+` is more efficient than `.+?`.

Comment: @sp00m no backtracking with either.

Comment: Both are probably very fast. TBH I didn't try to change or optimize OP's regex.

Comment: @sp00m [I tested](http://jsperf.com/regeee). On Chrome `[^"]*` is a little more efficient.

Comment: Thanks @dystroy it works perfectly! http://jsfiddle.net/b4hEj/5/